# Spring & Cucumber integration: @Sql import didn't execute

Tags: spring, testing, cucumber

I need to integrate the cucumber with spring in a practice. But I can't import some test data with spring's `@Sql` annotation. However the other integration tests that not use cucumber works fine. I didn't find why? The cucumber runner:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features={"classpath:features/"})
public class CucumberIT {

}
```

And the step defination:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={DevDbConfig.class})
@Sql("classpath:test-reader-data.sql")
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class StepDefines {

  @Autowired
  ReaderService readerService;

  Reader reader;

  @Given("^a user with name Lily$")
  public void a_user_with_name_Lily() throws Throwable {
    reader = readerService.findByName("Lily"); // reader is null here!
  }

  @Given("^this user Lily exists$")
  public void this_user_Lily_exists() throws Throwable {
      assertThat(reader, notNullValue());
  }

  @Then("^Lily's info should be returned$")
  public void lily_s_info_should_be_returned() throws Throwable {
      assertThat(reader.getName(), is("Lily"));
  }

}
```

But the following testing code can import the testing data normally:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={DevDbConfig.class})
@Sql("classpath:test-reader-data.sql")
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class ReaderServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  ReaderService readerService;

  @Autowired
  EntityManager entityManager;

  @Test
  public void testQueryByIdAndShouldNotReturnNull() {    
    Reader reader = readerService.findByName("Lily");
    assertThat(reader, notNullValue()); // reader is not null!
  }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `@Sql` will be executed by `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener`. The Spring `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` will register all of the `TestExecutionListener`s.

From the[`SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.html)java doc, it says:

> Scripts and inlined statements will be executed before or after execution of the corresponding test method, depending on the configured value of the executionPhase flag.

So a class level `@Sql` is equivalent to all `@Test`methods with individual `@Sql`annotation.

However, when cucumber is running, it won't execute any `@Test` method and the `@Sql` doesn't have chance to be executed.

Finally, I have to do it myself:

```
  @Autowired
  DataSource ds;

  @Given("^a user with name Lily$")
  public void a_user_with_name_Lily() throws Throwable {
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ds.getConnection(), new ClassPathResource("test-reader-data.sql"));
    reader = readerService.findByName("Lily");
  }

  @Given("^this user Lily exists$")
  public void this_user_Lily_exists() throws Throwable {
    assertThat(reader, notNullValue());
  }

  @Then("^Lily's info should be returned$")
  public void lily_s_info_should_be_returned() throws Throwable {
    assertThat(reader.getName(), is("Lily"));
  }
```